# How do I make light blue paint more interesting?

Tags: walls, paint, bedroom, design

My room has a very dull blue paint that causes boredom. I was looking for ways I could liven it up a bit.
[image: blue dull wall]

Comment: You could paint the room a different color

Comment: Are you allowed to paint, or fix stuff permanently to the walls, or do you have a landlord or similar who wouldn't allow that?

Comment: As it stands, your question is probably a bit too opinion-based and broad. Could you modify it a bit to make it more specific, such as "how can I attached decorations to the wall without making holes or repainting" or similar? Whichever fits your actual question best.

Comment: We don't do arts & crafts and decorating questions here. VtC

Comment: I work a lot with paint color.  Color does not cause boredom. Choices do. Make different choices.

Comment: that question can only be answered if you tell us what you find interesting, otherwise the question is silly

Comment: Think 1970s super graphics. A multi racing stripe that goes up and around the door opening. Or diagonals. Or daisies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like that blue and I choose something close too it for my room. I made one wall behind the bed an accent wall using wall paper.

White furniture and trims work nice with this color, black or dark wood items not so much.

[image]